# Link to login spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security, jsp-tags

I need to add a link to login page but i don't know how to make it,this is the link to logout

```
<c:if test="${pageContext['request'].userPrincipal != null}">
<c:out value=" | "/>
<span>
  <spring:url value="/resources/j_spring_security_logout" var="logout"/>
  <a href="${logout}">
    <spring:message code="security_logout"/>
  </a>
</span>
```

I've tried something like this

```
<c:if test="${pageContext['request'].userPrincipal == null}">
<c:out value=" | "/>
<span>
  <spring:url value="/resources/j_spring_security_login" var="login"/>
  <a href="${login}">
    <spring:message code="security_login"/>
  </a>
</span>
```

but it doesn't work .

Comment: You need to explain a bit more what "doesn't work" and what goes wrong. `j_spring_security_login` isn't a standard URL so unless you are providing support for it yourself you will get a 404. You should also show your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The default path for authentication is as below:

```
<c:url value="j_spring_security_check" var="url" />
<form action="${url}" method="post">

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="icon-lock icon-white"></i> Login
    </button>
</form>
```